# jQuery doesn't recognize a class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I have a edit button, when I press on it, it changes to "done" button.

It's all done by jQuery.

```
        $(".icon-pencil").click(function() {
            var pencil = $(this);
            var row = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
            row.find('td').not(":nth-last-child(2)").not(":last-child").each(function() {
                $(this).html("hi");
            });

            pencil.attr('class', 'icon-ok-sign');
        });

        //  save item
        $(".icon-ok-sign").click(function() {
            alert("hey");
        });
```

When I press on a "edit" ("`.icon-pencil`") button, its classes change to `.icon-ok-sign` (I can see in chrome console),

but when I click on it, no alert shown.

When I create a `<span class="icon-ok-sign">press</span>` and press on it, a alert displays.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `$( document ).on( "click", ".icon-ok-sign", function() {...`

Comment: Now it called twice. .

Comment: We need more information in order to determine why it is called twice.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you can not register click-events for future elements, you have to do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-ok-sign', function() {
 alert('hey');
});
```

> This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the
>   document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers
>   when content is dynamically added to a page.

Comment: Now it called twice. .

Comment: you have to remove your own click call:  $(".icon-ok-sign").click(function() {
            alert("hey");
        });

Comment: You just copied Stians answer!

Comment: i was typing it, after commit, i saw the same answer

Comment: @Mark I did and still called twice

Comment: is there any other code that does the same call?, based on your code here, it is not possible

Comment: @schlingel : there is only one valid answer, there all alike

Comment: @user1798362: is there other element that hass the same class icon-ok-sign?

Comment: @Mark No, this is the only one.

Comment: @user1798362: to have the alert called twice, there must be 2 elements that have the `icon-pencil` class that recieve the `icon-ok-sign` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use following script:

```
$(document).on('click','.icon-ok-sign',function(){
alert("hey");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".icon-pencil").click(function() {
            var pencil = $(this);
            var row = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
            row.find('td').not(":nth-last-child(2)").not(":last-child").each(function()            {
                $(this).html("hi");
            });

            pencil.removeAttr('class').addClass('icon-ok-sign');
        });

        //  save item
        $(".icon-ok-sign").click(function() {
            alert("hey");
        });
```